# Midrash Pertaining to the Rekindling of the Menorah Commemorated by Chanukah

Tags: midrash, chanuka, menorah--in-temple

The predominant traditional explanation for the eight days of *Chanukah* is the miracle of the oil: there was only enough pure oil to keep the *Menorah* fueled for a single day but it miraculously lasted the eight days needed to obtain more suitable oil (*Shabbos* 21b).

A number of year ago I recall seeing a traditional (but early and somewhat obscure) *midrash* that gave an alternative (but not necessarily mutually exclusive) explanation to the effect that the Maccabee's erected the *Menorah* from eight "iron spits" (as I recall) they encountered entering the sanctuary. It was cited in an article, I believe it was on Torah Musings but can no longer find it despite having searched several times.

Can anyone identify the "*midrash*" in question or the article it was cited in?

Comment: [*M'nachos* 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.28b.12?lang=bi): "אמרו לו משם ראיה? שפודים של ברזל היו וחיפום בבעץ". [*M'gillas Ta'anis*](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillat_Ta'anit%2C_Kislev.8?lang=bi): "ומה ראו להדליק את הנרות אלא בימי מלכות יון שנכנסו בית חשמונאי להיכל שבעה שפודין של ברזל בידם וחפום בעץ והדליקו בהם את המנורה".

Comment: Huh, that's not exactly as obscure as I remembered! :D